# Schedule push notification time in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a requirement in my app to remind user using push notification I have implemented push notification in-app and nodeJS using firebase. but how I can send push notification to any user by stored date time in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality in the Firebase Cloud Messaging API to send a message at a certain time. If you need to send the message at a different time, you will have to schedule your code that calls the FCM API to be run at that time.

An alternative is to **send** the message now, but only display it on the device at a certain time. To do this, you'd send a data message, and hand then let your application code on the device handle the delay until it's time to display it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how can i hand the message in front end, do you have any idea

Comment: @Kanna'nHassouna look at notifee